# How to get metrics for a request on CosmosDB graph collection?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to find out details about a Gremlim query - so I set the `PopulateQueryMetrics` property of the `FeedOptions` argument to `true`.

But the `FeedResponse` object I get back doesn't have the `QueryMetrics` property populated.

```
var queryString = $"g.addV('{d.type}').property('id', '{d.Id}')";
var query = client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(graphCollection, queryString,
    new FeedOptions {
        PopulateQueryMetrics = true
    });
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    FeedResponse<dynamic> response = await query.ExecuteNextAsync();
    //response.QueryMetrics is null
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I created my Azure Cosmos DB account with Gremlin (graph) API, and I could encounter the same issue as you mentioned. I found a tutorial [Monitoring and debugging with metrics in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-metrics) and read the **Debugging why queries are running slow** section as follows:

> **In the SQL API SDKs**, Azure Cosmos DB provides query execution statistics.

```html
IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
 UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName), 
 “SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.city = ‘Seattle’”, 
 new FeedOptions 
 { 
 PopulateQueryMetrics = true, 
 MaxItemCount = -1, 
 MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1, 
 EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true 
 }).AsDocumentQuery();
FeedResponse<dynamic> result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync();

// Returns metrics by partition key range Id 
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, QueryMetrics> metrics = result.QueryMetrics;
```

Then, I queried my Cosmos DB Gremlin (graph) account via the SQL API above, I retrieved the `QueryMetrics` as follows:

[image]

**Note:** I also checked that you could specify the SQL expression like this `SELECT * FROM c where c.id='thomas' and c.label='person'`. For adding new Vertex, I do not know how to construct the SQL expression. Moreover, the `CreateDocumentAsync` method does not support the `FeedOptions` parameter.

Per my understanding, the `PopulateQueryMetrics` setting may only work when using the SQL API. You could add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599065-azure-cosmos-db-graph-api).